# Angular 2 how to compile a template and save the result html

Tags: angular, angular2-template, templating

Ok, by now I have to create a body for an e-mail.

**I need to take a template, interpolate it with the data I already have (js Object) and have this resulted html string in a variable**, so I can send this body to a server that will actually send the e-mail.

I am not sure about using other template engine, handlebars for instance, to generate this html.

**Is there a way to use the angular 2 template engine? Keep in mind that I dont need to show it, I want to keep it in memory only.**

If I cant use it what should I use? Is there any best known or recomended aprouch?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need it but here is some ideas:

```
import {Component, NgModule, Input, VERSION, ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {Injectable, ComponentFactoryResolver, ApplicationRef, Injector} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector:'my-cmp',
  template: 'here is {{title}}'
})
export class MyComponent {
  @Input() title: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <input #inp>
    <button (click)="create(inp.value)">Create</button>
  `,
})
export class App {
  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
              private appRef: ApplicationRef,
              private injector: Injector) {
  }

  create(title) {
    let factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyComponent);
    let ref = factory.create(this.injector);
    ref.instance.title = title;
    this.appRef.attachView(ref.hostView);

    console.log(ref.location.nativeElement);

    this.appRef.detachView(ref.hostView);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App , MyComponent],
  entryComponents: [MyComponent],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```